# Every api request session id is changing

Tags: magento2, magento-graphql

my backend is magento 2 with graphql and in front-side we are using next js so my problem is for on every request in api response set-cookie header gives different PHP session id but i have to maintain the same session id. For next js api call we use apollo client. Frontend and backend both are on different domain for example frontend domains is **web.magento.com** and backend domain is **back.magento.com**.[image]